# Allow user role to access a specific plugin WORDPRESS

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar, user-roles, wp-admin

I am using Amelia booking calendar, and I also have a custom user role called "Instructor" which works great with LearnDash. I have enabled multi-role for users using PHP, so my instructors can also be Amelia Employees.

Here's the scenario:

1) A user role "Amelia employee" goes to WP-ADMIN and can see the Amelia plugin menu item on the backend sidebar and its allowed settings.

2) A user role "Amelia employee" AND "Instructor" cannot see the Amelia plugin menu item on the backend.

3) A user role "Amelia employee" AND "Instructor" can access the Amelia plugin settings only if I type the URL in the browser, but does not see the menu item itself.

My hypothesis is that the custom-role "Instructor" is limiting what this user can see in the back-end - thus hiding the "Amelia" menu item.

How do I allow "Instructor"s to see the "Amelia" item on the backend WP-ADMIN dashboard? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Member by memberpress plugin and edit the "Instructor" user's permission

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to give the capability to what ever role you want.

```
function add_cap_custom_role() {
  $role = get_role( 'instructor' );
  
  if ( !$role->capabilities[ 'manage_options' ] && !$role->capabilities[ 'edit_posts' ] ) {
    $role->add_cap( 'manage_options' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_posts' );
  }
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_cap_custom_role' );
```