# Give a custom role access to ONLY ONE plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-capabilities, wordpress-roles

I created a custom role called `Marketing Team`. I would like to give users with this role access to one specific plugin called `XYZ Plugin` (I want this role to see XYZ Plugin from the sidebar menu, and be able to use it). If I add a capability called `manage_options` to this role, it will have access to all plugins, and I don't want that.

Adding a custom capability (e.g. `access_xyz_plugin`) and assigning this capability to a role so that role will have access to `XYZ Plugin` -- will this work?

I've done extensive research on Google, but none of the solutions seem to work, or none of them is similar to what exactly I want to achieve.

I believe my issue is similar to this:
[Allow user role to access a specific plugin WORDPRESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61927492/allow-user-role-to-access-a-specific-plugin-wordpress?rq=2)

But none of answers provided correctly addressed the question.

Comment: You can filter the admin menu items, https://dev.to/jackharner/custom-menu-order-in-the-wordpress-admin-l36 Although that will only remove the links, it will not prevent a user who would _know_ which the appropriate URLs are, from still accessing the _functionality_. But if you wanted the latter, then that probably would not work without modifying the plugin directly, I suppose.

Comment: Is this `XYZ Plugin` your code? Or is it somebody else's?

Comment: Step. 1 Check if its admin page. Step 2 check if its xyz role. 3 if so hide admin menu items as sugested and in case someone try to access those pages redirect to xyz plugin page. Thats all. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_menu_page/ . Some examples how restrict / redirect - https://aristath.github.io/blog/restrict-access-wordpress-dashboard